# Port Forwarding

Tags: networking, rhel, port-forwarding

How can I check to see a list of available 'port'/'protocol' (please correct this) forwarding on Redhat?

The following sends me to the 'gateway' of my deployment:

```
[<user>.IE03] → ssh root@<hostname>.<network>
[root@<hostname> ~]# >
```

and this sends me to the 'master server' of the deployment:

```
[<user>.IE03] → ssh -p 2242 root@<hostname>.<network>
[root@<new_hostname> ~]#
```

I'm looking to find out how I can find the -p [port/protocol] for the other servers in the deployment.

Are these listed somewhere? Is there a command I can run to check this?

Comment: Ask the person who set it up?

Comment: I work in a big company. I'm not sure how I'd go about tracking down the person who implemented it.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do so:

1. Ask the IT department for this
2. Run a nmap scan on the whole subnet, `nmap -sS <subnet>`, to check for open SSH ports

The second method is impractical and will likely trigger a network alert (and get you into trouble), so I wholeheartedly recommend you apply #1.

Comment: I run `nmap` a lot on our machines at work. Keep forgetting the IP addresses of the machines that are accessible via `ssh`!

Comment: @maulinglawns What about writing them down in a doc? ;)

Comment: True, I could do that, but you get extra geek points when you use `nmap` (or so I've been told)...

Comment: dr01, would this be safe to run on a test environment deployment? where would I run this command? the gateway?

Comment: @maulinglawns You get extra geek points also for maintaining a well-structured, complete, updated documentation about your environment :)

Comment: @dr01 Spot on. And I like to think I do (most of the time!).

Comment: @tehjoker nmap is safe to use (albeit likely to trigger IDSs and the like, as I said).  You run this on your local machine.  Are you sure you don't want to try option #1 first?  After all, if they didn't tell you the open ports on the remote servers, perhaps you are not supposed to ssh to them...

Comment: `nmap` is not likely to be of any use here. This was likely done as the remote hosts are not directly accessible, so `nmap` won't find them. And `nmap`ing the host which is doing the redirections isn't going to tell you what the ports map to, or even whether the port is forwarded (it could be a service local to that host).